# Citrix/Outlook 2003: "SBCMSYNC.DLL is not a valid Office Addin"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, citrix

When a user starts Outlook 2003 from within Citrix, they receive the error:

> SBCMSYNC.DLL is not a valid Office Addin

How is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235009 looks like the solution to your problem, though oddly I only see this fault referenced for users of 2000 or 2002.

Have you installed 2000 before then upgraded to 2003?

Either way, if you have 2000 disk #2 with you, try inserting that and running through its 'repair' or 'maintenance' install.

Comment: @PriceChild: Are you sure this applies to someone logging into Citrix first, then starting Outlook from within Citrix?  Citrix is a thin-client environment, running applications from the server, so the user will have no ability to repair applications on the server.

Comment: Bah, I completely missed those 3 words. Still, googling around for the problem I figure it will be something similar to the answer I've given.

Comment: @PriceChild: But you still can't run a repair or install a Citrix application from a client.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Citrix but surely you must have installed the application yourself somehow?

Comment: @PriceChild.  No, Citrix applications are server-based, and installed on the server.  I am not the Citrix administrator unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, so can't you suggest this to the Citrix administrator then?